# Addition of value for each key in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created a dictionary that has a meter number as the key and a list for the value. For example: Meter1 has index 0 value 45 and index 1 value 65. I was wondering the most efficient way to add index 0 for each of the meter numbers together? I am trying to get the max added value at a given index. The lists will be the same length. I have attached the code I have to create the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (string ertNumber in ertNumberList)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(ertNumber))
    {
        List<string> meterReadings = new List<string>();
        meterReadings = getValuesFromOID(ertNumber);
        dictionary.Add(ertNumber, meterReadings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these `meterReadings` numeric? why would you be storing them as strings?

Comment: They are numeric, I need to change that!

Comment: It looks like `getValuesFromOID` probably calls some sort of database query or interface that is returning raw data.  It would help you and your code maintainability if you returned a domain model object with meaningful field names and correct data types to work with instead of a context-less list of `string` with mixed data.

Comment: And why are you using a `List<string>` for the value if the values is/are just one or more numeric values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to get the max added value at a given index.

To get the max value at a each index try this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> dictionary = ... // NOTE: use some numeric type
Dictionary<string, double> maxima = dictionary.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.Max());
```

This will produce a new dictionary which stores the maximum for every value at each index in the source dictionary.

---

**Update**

So you have this structure

```
"Meter1", [ 15, 5, 10 ]
"Meter2", [ 10, 50, 20 ]
```

And you want to compute the maximum value of the sum of meter readings at any index. Let's assume that each `List<double>` is the same length, then if I'm understanding correctly, that would be:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> dictionary = ...
var length = dictionary.First().Value.Length;
var maximum = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                        .Select(i => dictionary.Values.Select(d => d[i]).Sum())
                        .Max(); // 55
```

If you also want to get the *index* where this is the maximum you can use this:

```
var result =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, length)
     let s = dictionary.Values.Select(d => d[i]).Sum()
     orderby s descending
     select new { Index = i, Sum = s })
    .First(); // { Index = 1, Sum = 55 }
```

Comment: This is really close! This gets me the maximum for each of the lists but I am looking for the lists added together (by index only) then find the max of the added values. For Example: Meter1: (0,15) , (1,5) (2, 10)  Meter2: (0,10) , (1,50) (2, 20) Result: (25) (55) (30) and the added max is 55. The 0, 1, 2 are merely indexes. Sorry I have been vague, its been a long day

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the meter readings were changed to int, you can use LINQ:

```
var maxMeterValue = dictionary[myertNumber].Max(v => v);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, which handles lists of non-equal lengths:

```
var maxLength = dictionary.Values.Max(readings => readings.Count);

var sums = Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    .Select(i => readings.Where(rs => i < rs.Count).Sum(rs => int.Parse(rs[i]));

var maxSum = sums.Max();
```

There is certainly a more efficient way to do this, but I am pretty sure it would require more typing.